# Fetching data after a post request will bring back old data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

this is my very first question here, i have been playing with the web technologies only for few months, so what i am going to ask might be something trivial, but i can't seem  to solve this issue by my self.

What i am trying to do here is to open a modal and with a form to post some data to my express back-end. After i get the response from the server i send it through props to the parent component.

```
const CreateAccount = (props) => {
  // context
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  const [accountType, setAccountType] = useState("standard");
  const [accountCurrency, setAccountCurrency] = useState("ron");

  const { post, loading, error } = useFetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}` },
  });

  const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const response = await post("/accounts", { accountType, accountCurrency });
    console.log(response.data);
    props.setHttpResponse(response.message);

    // if modal is given, close it after submiting the form
    props.closeModal && props.closeModal();
  };
```

The response consists of a message and the updated document. Everything works fine, the document is saved in the DB properly, i get the expected response, and the parent component rerenders after the response is sent

Here in the parent component i have the useEffect function that should get the data when the component mounts for the first time and each time the response from the modal is set(so wherever i send a post request). The component re renders indeed, and i get a response from the server, but the issue is that the response i get is the old one, not the updated one with the new data which was set on the post request i sent moments before in that modal.

```
const InitializedPage = () => {
  Modal.setAppElement("#modal");
  // context
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const [createAccountResponse, setCreateAccountResponse] = useState(""); // the response i get from the modal after i send post request to the server
  const { loading, get } = useFetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}`,
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    },
  });

  // get data for specific user
  useEffect(() => {
    const { userId } = authContext.userData;
    (async () => {
      const response = await get(`/users/${userId}`);
      console.log(response); // here the response is the old one whenever the component rerenders
      setUserData(response.userData);
    })(); 
  }, [get, authContext, createAccountResponse]);
```

If someone could, please, tell me what i am missing or what i am doing wrong here?

EDIT: I forgot to add that if i refresh the page i will get the updated data.

Comment: Inside CreateAccount, you are setting a response message in props. Does InitializedPage's useEffect have that prop that you passed in  CreateAccount?

Comment: `
          <CreateAccount
            closeModal={handleModalClose}
            setHttpResponse={setCreateAccountResponse}
          />
          ` 
          Yes, here is where i set the createAccountResponse state, which is
          in useEffect function.